# How to convert an Image to Grayscale in CSS/JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, html5-canvas

I wanted an image (set as background) to be converted to Grayscale in Javascript/CSS

The Problem here is that the CSS3 filters for grayscale do not work in IE
And since the image is a crossdomain resource I am not able to read the data from canvas.
My target browsers are Firefox, Chrome, IE10 onwards

I have tried using the below

```
filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'1 0 0 0 0, 0 1 0 0 0, 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");
```

This does not work in IE10 and IE11

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svgroot" viewBox="0 0 400 377" width="400" height="377">
  <defs>
     <filter id="filtersPicture">
       <feComposite result="inputTo_38" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SourceGraphic" operator="arithmetic" k1="0" k2="1" k3="0" k4="0" />
       <feColorMatrix id="filter_38" type="saturate" values="0" data-filterid="38" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(&quot;#filtersPicture&quot;)" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="377" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="whateverpathtoimage.jpg" />
</svg>
```

I am not able to set this SVG as background image for a div.

Is there any SVG solution for the same? or probably if someone know how to read an entire image in javascript and convert every pixel to grayscale?

Comment: Either drop IE support or have the file converted on your server, i don't see other solution. Droping IE seems best : anyway, unless corporate, people using I.E. nowadays just didn't get what the web is about...

Comment: No idea whether this works for SVG images, but you might try `DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(grayscale=1)`. Otherwise, you should try Google; `javascript grayscale image` returns lots of hits.

Comment: @Palpatim Did not help googling.

Comment: @GameAlchemist IE support is required. Its used by around 20% of our users. Can't help it.

Answer (score 0):

Your filter has some strangeness in it which may be causing problems. Your filter should be:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 377" width="400px" height="377px">
  <defs>
     <filter id="filtersPicture">
       <feColorMatrix type="saturate" values="0"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>
  <image filter="url(#filtersPicture)" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="377"  xlink:href="whateverpathtoimage.jpg" />
</svg>
```

Comment: This does not help. It created an image. I want it to be a background image. Any way I can extract data in Base-64 format using Javascript and apply a background image?